# What's that called?

Tags: angular

I'd like to know what that's called?
It's a piece of code I found in an app.

```
 <app-counter [counterDatasObservable]="dataMlsService.getProducts('EnCours', 'Location')"></app-counter>
```

The getProducts method makes an API call that creates a database query and this method takes 2 parameters.
I'd like to do this method twice to make it look something like this.

```
<app-counter [counterDatasObservable]="dataMlsService.getProducts('EnCours', 'Location'), dataMlsService.getProducts('Compromis', 'Vente')"></app-counter>
```

thanks

Edit :
counter.ts

```
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() counterDatasObservable: Observable<any>;
  data = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counterDatasObservable.subscribe( datas => {
      this.data = datas;    
    });
  }
}
```

parent-service.ts

```
readonly ApiUrl = "publication/Mls/";

      constructor(private apiClient: ApiClientService){}
      
      getProducts(status: string, typeTransac: string): Observable <any> {

        let params = new HttpParams();
//A faire : inclure params date
        params = params.append('status', status);
        params = params.append('typeTransac', typeTransac);

        
        if (status !== null && typeTransac !== null) {
            return this.apiClient.get(this.ApiUrl, { params: params});
        }else{
            console.log('aucune valeur en params')
        }
    }
```

Comment: I’m afraid that is called a code-smell..

Comment: `[counterDatasObservable]` is used to input data to the component `app-counter`. it's a decorator called [`input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).dataMlsService.getProducts('EnCours', 'Location')` must return a array or something. you can't do `[counterDatasObservable]="dataMlsService.getProducts('EnCours', 'Location'), dataMlsService.getProducts('Compromis', 'Vente')"` i think it will give an error for sure.

Comment: That's right. That gives me a mistake. 
But is there any other way?

Comment: can you edit the app-counter component ?

Comment: the post is edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way you can resolve your problem

- Counter.ts

> ```
> export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {
>   @Input() counterDatasObservable: Observable<any>;
>   @Input() counterDatasObservable2: Observable<any>;
>   data = [];
>
>   constructor() {}
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>     this.counterDatasObservable.subscribe(datas => {
>       this.data = datas;
>     });
>
>     this.counterDatasObservable2.subscribe(datas => {
>       //your code
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```

- DOM

> <app-counter
> [counterDatasObservable]="dataMlsService.getProducts('EnCours',
> 'Location')"
> [counterDatasObservable2]="dataMlsService.getProducts('Compromis',
> 'Vente')"">